# How to reach the "software sources" dialog from Plasma Discover

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde

In Kubuntu 16.04 Muon Discover had a dialog called ["software sources" (you will have to scroll down to see it)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Kubuntu#Managing_Repositories_in_Kubuntu).
Now in Kubuntu 16.10 the same tool is simply called [(Plasma) Discover](http://news.softpedia.com/news/kubuntu-16-04-lts-arrives-with-new-plasma-discover-software-center-kde-plasma-5-503315.shtml) but lacks the dialog "software sources".

Is there a replacement for it? If not: does that mean that automatic update notification and automatic update installation are gone?

Comment: I found out that the dialog is called `software-properties-kde` and it can be started from the command line or using the Plasma search (`kdesudo software-properties-kde`). I don't know if it still actually does something nor if there is a way to get there without knowing the command.

Comment: After some research I am not the only one facing the issue: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=309&t=133415#p358775

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Kubuntu 20.04 it seems that the "software sources" dialog disappeared for good. This is unfortunate because Kubuntu 20.04 happens to be a long term support (LTS) release and the user must open the "software sources" dialog to allow updates to normal releases (i.e. update to 20.10 instead of waiting for 22.04 LTS).
`kdesudo` was [deprecated](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/73471-Kdesudo) and `software-properties-kde` is now called `software-properties-qt`. So in Kubuntu 20.04 starting `sudo software-properties-qt` from a console did the trick.

In case you want to try at your own risk: after modifying the upgrade channel from LTS to normal releases you can force the upgrade from Kubuntu 20.04 to Kubuntu 20.10 with `pkexec do-release-upgrade -d -m desktop -f DistUpgradeViewKDE`. Removing `-d` will only let you upgrade after Kubuntu 20.10 is officially released, which will happen next week (October 22nd, 2020). But sometimes Kubuntu fails to find the new release and `-d` must be used even after the official release date.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution in Kubuntu 18.04: click on the button "settings" in the bottom left corner, then click on the hamburger menu (the square button with three stripes) in the top right corner, then click on "software sources". I am not sure if it works in Kubuntu 16.04 though.

Answer (score 0):

Kubuntu 19.10
open Discover and you will find Sources in bottom left. I wonder why can't it be searchable in launcher menu...